# In tkinter when I create a second window using Toplevel then both window appear in under same program, how to make them appear different?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, toplevel

I have made a tkinter based windows application that in which 2 window get created which show some simple global variable that are displayed in both window and can be changed by entering value in any window too, everything is working fine only problem is taskbar label comes grouped together in windows taskbar which makes it difficult to navigate between two windows,  it there any way both windows appear separately in windows taskbar.( NOT by using windows inbuilt option to make all taskbar labels separate)

this is my code it's just a basic code to show my problem.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("root win 1")

Label(root, text='this is first window').pack()

def extra_root():
    new_root = Toplevel(root)
    new_root.title("root win 2")
    new_root.geometry("200x200")
    
    Button(new_root,text='this is 2nd window' , command=None).pack()


    new_root.mainloop()
#to create 2nd window
Button(root, command=extra_root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[this is my how it comes currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yi0N.png)

[this is how I want it to appear (this is achieved by using windows inbuilt feature to make all taskbar label to appear separately)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDKyK.png)

Comment: I think that that is controlled by your OS (Windows). Also you only need 1 `.mainloop()` in your program most of the time so you can remove the `new_root.mainloop()`

Comment: The items in the taskbar are separate applications running, so just creating a `Toplevel` windows doesn't do that. You could launch another Python script several different ways, but they would have nothing to do with the one that launched them (without some kind of interprocess communication that you would have implement yourself).

Comment: there must be some way, i think group = wm_group(args)  does something like that telling windows to create group of program but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/wm.html             see here for more window manager comands